# How do I locally test a node.js + mongodb app that works in Heroku?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I know how to run a regular node.js app locally, using `foreman`, but when my app is linked to a MongoHQ database in Heroku, the connection is part of the heroku environment.

Is there a way I can test the application on my local machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreman will load environment variables specified in the `.env` file of your app. It's in the [Local setup](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#local-setup) section of the [Configuration and Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) Dev Center article. There's a [plugin](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-config) to Heroku toolbelt that lets you pull the config from your running app, if that's what you want to use (you might also want to consider running a MongoDB server locally):

```
$ heroku plugins:install git://github.com/ddollar/heroku-config.git
$ heroku config:pull --overwrite --interactive
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing `foreman` on your local machine? Take a look at the `Procfile` and see which processes it manages. There's probably nothing special about the Heroku machine's connection to MongoHQ. Just grep around for mongohq in the project and you'll probably find some configuration for the database connection.

Comment: As I said, I've already ran the app on my local machine using `foreman`. Thanks anyway!